# MySQL Delete Duplicate data using Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to delete duplicate records from student table. I am using MySQL server version 5.7

```
create table student (
   sid int not null,
   sname varchar(50) not null,
   city varchar(50) not null
) ;
```

Delete duplicate records using self join **is working fine**

```
 delete t1 from student as t1
 inner join student as t2
 on t1.sid < t2.sid and t1.sname = t2.sname;
```

Delete duplicate records using sub query **is not working**

```
delete s1 from student
where sid > (select sid from (select min(sid) from student s2 
where s2.sname = sname) as t);
```

I tried instruction mentioned in the below link also

[Delete duplicate rows using Sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565486/delete-duplicate-rows-using-sub-query)

It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the `join` version.  The problem with the subquery version is that MySQL does not recognize correlation clauses nested more than one level.

That makes it hard to construct the query.  While possible, it is not really worth it.  You know the right approach in MySQL.  And the nested subqueries is really a hack to get around MySQL limitations that are not needed in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery method is not working because your second nested query

```
select min(sid) from student s2 where s2.sname = sname
```

does not reference the table you want to delete from, i.e. the `sname` in `s2.sname = sname` references the same `s2` table, so the subquery is the same as

```
select min(sid) from student s2 where s2.sname = s2.sname
```

If you want to stick to a subquery method, you should [use a derived table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44971214/12032448) like so:

```
DELETE FROM
   student
WHERE EXISTS ( 
   SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM student) AS s2
     WHERE s2.sname = student.sname AND student.sid > s2.sid)
```